# jQuery change html value that is saved in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html code saved in a variable called myHtml

```
<div>
    <p data-id="1">A</p>
    <p data-id="2">B</p>
    <p data-id="3">C</p>
</div>
```

I need to change the value of before appending this to html.

My code doesn't change the value

```
$(myHtml).find('p[data-id="1"]').text("new text");
```

Also need to consider changing src of an image like

```
<img src="image.jpg" />
```

So I need something like

```
$(myHtml).find('img').attr("src", "new-image.jpg");
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to wrap `myHtml` with `$` for applying jQuery code

```
$(myHtml).find('p[data-id="1"]').text("new text");
```

To get that updated value use following method,

```js
var myHtml = '<div>' +
  '<p data-id="1">A</p>' +
  '<p data-id="2">B</p>' +
  '<p data-id="3">C</p>' +
  '</div>';
myHtml = $(myHtml).find('p[data-id="1"]').text("new text").end()[0].outerHTML;
alert(myHtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work when html was saved in a variable.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm still finding a solution.

Comment: @EdiboyIlagan `myHtml=$(myHtml).find('p[data-id="1"]').text("new text").end()[0].outerHTML;
alert(myHtml);`

Comment: It's a great answer, but it would be much better if you explained what does end() does. Thanks so much anyway.

Comment: @AboElnouR : it switches to the previous filter/selector in the chain, here it will be `$(myHtml)`

Comment: @PranavCBalan I knew that, but I think explaining it will be a good addition to your answer, thanks